# How do you install the Haskell Platform over a previous install?

Tags: macos, haskell, installation

I've been working with Haskell lately, and installed gtk2hs (a gtk library for Haskell) a few days ago using MacPorts. For some reason, MacPorts saw fit to install GHC 6.10 over my previous GHC 6.12 install, but I didn't really care.

Now I find myself desiring the improved parallelism support of the latest Haskell Platform, so I installed it today, and it installed successfully - except that when I type in "ghc -v" in Terminal, I am informed that I have GHC 6.10 still.

I have tried using uninstall-hs, and it informs me that I have three Haskells on my system: versions 6.12, 6.12.3, and 7.04. I'm not sure how that 6.12.3 showed up, and what happened to the 6.10? Most importantly, how can I start running version 7.04? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4):

You should completely purge your MacPorts install of GHC and your current Platform installation and install the Haskell Platform directly with the [OS X installer](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/mac.html). After that, future versions of the Haskell Platform can be upgraded to cleanly simply by installing them.

The following command should remove your MacPorts GHC:

```
$ sudo port uninstall --follow-dependents ghc
```

You might want to execute something like `find /usr /opt/local -name '*ghc*'` after uninstalling everything to check that there's no remaining traces.

Comment: Thanks for the command!. However, this did not answer how to force Mac ports to install desired version. I have GHC 7.8 and want to move to GHC 7.10

Answer (score 2):

To really clear out the old install, you've got to go in and delete things by hand.

This will be very useful: [Everywhere that GHC/Haskell Platform installs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884478/everywhere-that-ghc-haskell-platform-installs)

Might want to look here also: http://www.vex.net/~trebla/haskell/sicp.xhtml

Comment: +1; I doubt this is necessary for the MacPorts install — it should have complete knowledge of the installed locations — but it'll help for removing the Platform installation.

Comment: @ehird: That might not be true: I had major difficulties uninstalling the Haskell Platform which came from a MacPorts install.