# Configuring cabal on Max OS X 10.9

Tags: macos, config, cabal

When I run `cabal install Cabal cabal-install` I have this warning:

```
Warning: The directory
/Users/arthurfayzrakhmanov/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.6.3/lib/cabal-install-1.18.0.2/bin
is not in the system search path.
```

Looks like something misconfigured, because I saw similar message when I've installed `happy`, but it pointed to `/Users/arthurfayzrakhmanov/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.6.3/lib/happy...`.

How should I configure cabal on OS X 10.9.1, I mean PATH and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open your ~/.bash_profile with any editor you're comfortable with
2. Append this to the file: `export PATH="$HOME/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.6.3/lib/cabal-install-1.20.0.0/bin:$PATH"`
3. Save file and close editor
4. In terminal type `source ~/.bash_profile`

Then to test, in Terminal type `which cabal`, and you should see it pointing to the new path.

Answer (score 0):

After few attempts to solve [prior issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20801824/1749901) with OS X Mavericks I've reinstalled entire platform with Homebrew, and issue dismissed. If you need help with that see mentioned answer.